# function in where clause+ axapta2009

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I am having `Illegal use of WHERE expression` for the following statement

```
select dateField from tableName
where dayname(dayofwk(tableName.dateField)) like 'sunday';
```

Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a function in a where clause, or in any select statement

Answer (score 3):

Anthony is right, of course. However, there are still at leat 2 options to acheive the same result.

- Create a new integer field in your table. This field should store the return value of the dayOfWk() function. Later you can easily query this table.
- Second option - create a View inside AX and use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx) feature toghether with the [datePart() SQL Server function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx). Something like datepart(dw, tableName.DateField) should do it.

The first option will probably result in better performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use any function on any field of the same table for which you are using the query